# Animation for a chain reaction/ cascade type build up in mathematica

Tags: animation

I am looking forward to suggestions to develop an animation such as a nuclear chain reaction/ particle cascade buildup (particularly as in the attached image: gluon cascade) using mathematica animation. I want to use the animation for my presentation.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this site is about fixing specific issues with existing code. Your request is too vague and it contains no code. If you’d rather have it done for you, you should hire a consultant.

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NuclearFission/) demonstration for ideas.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no well-posed question in this post; the OP is simply asking for somebody to act as a free coding service.

Comment: @MarcoB : I would differ with your view. You did not read my question right. I asked for "suggestion" and not any particular code. Even the suggestion for the set up I asked (i.e. nuclear fission) is far from that in figure conceptual wise. Please take a little more care answering next time.

Comment: @m_goldberg : Same goes here again. I asked for suggestion for a similar set up conceptualise and not provide me a free code. If you can't help, there's a word in the dictionary "ignore" rather than patronize. Hope you understand :-)

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi : Thanks for the link..trying to get the ideas from here :-)

Comment: @souvikpriyamadhya nothing personal in those comments, take a look at asking guidelines: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started:

We first create a grid of "atoms" and set their state to inactive: 0 and activate the middle cell by setting its state to 1;

```
n = 100;
grid = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, n}, {y, n}], 1];
state = <|Thread[grid -> 0]|>; state[Round[{n, n}/2]] = 1;
```

Then we define a function "step" that searches active cells and makes them emit 2 "neutrons" in x or y opposite directions and turns the cell state to spent: -1. If a neutron hits an inactive cell it makes it active:

```
step[pos_] := Module[{new, st},
  st = RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
  new = pos + st;
  While[state[new] == -1, new += st];
  If[state[new] == 0 || state[new] == -1 , state[new] = 1];
  new = pos - st;
  While[state[new] == -1, new -= st];
  If[state[new] == 0 || state[new] == -1 , state[new] = 1]
  ]
```

Finally we plot the grid and create a button that updates the grid stepwise:

```
Dynamic@MatrixPlot[Partition[(state // Normal)[[All, 2]], n]]
Button["Step", step /@ Keys[Select[state, # == 1 &]];]
```

[image]

Comment: Haber : Thanks for the suggestion. I shall certainly borrow the ideas in order to build up my animation. :-)